# Javascript slider is not working

Tags: jquery

I am tring to build a small slider that has multiple boxes. I have 8 (for example) and I need to have 4 displayed at a time. They are like small banners that I want to slide up.

Here is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="boxes">
    <div class="current">1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div class='box hide'>5</div>
    <div class='box hide'>6</div>
    ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#boxes div{
    width:400px;
    height:60px;
    background-color: red;
    color:white;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.hide{display:none;}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(show_boxes, 2000);
})

function show_boxes(){

     var curBox = $("#boxes div.current");
     var nxtBox = curBox.next();

     if(nxtBox.length == 0){
         nxtBox =  $("#boxes div:first");
     }

     curBox.removeClass('current').addClass('hide');
     nxtBox.addClass('current').removeClass('hide');

}
```

Comment: This is a mess, any way you can give us a jsFiddle, as well as explain what it does and doesn't do?  No real idea what you're trying to accomplish or what's going wrong.

Comment: If helping you, please check http://jsfiddle.net/haapN/

Comment: Ever consider that `nxtBox` is the second box instead of the 5th box which is the one you want to change?  Also, consider what happens after you go past the 8th box in terms of showing it?  Those would be my suggestions for starting points to fix this.

Comment: I had a halfway working solution, then I accidentally started adding elements to DOM recursively and borked my computer.  @PeterVR's answer looks like it might work though.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it something like this:

```
function show_boxes() {
    // cache the boxes wrapper (for performance)
    var $boxes = $('#boxes');
    // fetch the box we want to hide, which is on top of the list
    var $toHide = $boxes.find('div:first');
    // add it to the end of the list
    $boxes.append($toHide);
    // hide it
    $toHide.addClass('hide');
    // show the next box, which is now always the first hidden one
    $boxes.find('.hide:first').removeClass('hide');
}
```

Note that I move the top box to the end of the list each time. This way you will get a nice infinite loop, and you do not have to do complex checks to see which box is the next one to show, and which is the next one to hide.

A demonstration:
http://jsfiddle.net/XzmAT/2/

Also I removed the `current` class, as it is not needed in my code.

Comment: One problem. I need to display 4 boxes all the time, and the rest to be slide up. can you give me a hint?

Comment: 4 boxes are showing in the fiddle. What exactly do you mean by slide up?

Comment: Initial they are 4, but after they run, it remain only one box, which is changing, but i need that allways to be displayed 4 boxes. understaind my ideea? (sorry for my bad english). best regards, Stefan

Comment: Are you not seeing 4 boxes at all time in my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XzmAT/2/ ? If so, what browser are you using?

Comment: I am sorry @PeterVR, i thing i check the my first link. You are right, my mistake. Thanks and best regards! PS: there is a way to rate your effort? you really deserve it :D